# Excel Array formula IF(multiple criteria)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

In my spreadsheet, comparing headphones, our instruction is basically to use as many different formulas as possible.

So as part of the spreadsheet, I would like to be able to show the most expensive headphones *per manufacturer*, cheapest per manufacturer, best rated per manufacturer etc...
So far I have been able to get some mostly working array formulas.

For example, this formula works to get the *model* of the manufacturer "Sennheiser" with the highest price:

```
=INDEX($Data.$B$5:$L$32,SMALL(IF($Data.$E$5:$E$32 = $Sheet2.D17, ROW($Data.$B$5:$E$32) - ROW($Data.$B$5) + 1, ROW($Data.$E$32) + 1), 1), 2)
```

Column E is the Price column and D17 is a pre-calculated Max price for "sennheiser"

This works fine, until you get 2 headphones with the same price / rating or whatever. THen it starts returning the wrong values.

So I tried various solutions that I found on the interwebs, like

```
AND(condition1, condition2) 
condition1 * AND(cndition2)
condition1 * condition2
```

but none of this seems to work with an array formula for some reason. I get #N/A or #VALUE and various other errors.
SO basically I would like to know how to modify my formula, or even a completely new formula, to check for lowest price AND the correct manufacturer.

I hope my question is clear, so I have uploaded the spreadsheet to get some idea of what I am talking about.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18816338/Stats%20Analysis%20%20%281%29.xlsm

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should this have a [tag:homework] tag as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically AND won't work here because AND returns a single result rather than an array....but * should be OK, i.e. try this formula in B3

`=INDEX(Data!C$5:C$32,MATCH(1,(Data!$E$5:$E$32=$D3)*(Data!$B$5:$B$32=$A3),0))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copied to C3 and then down both columns

That will find the first match for both price and manufacturer and return the relevant model/type

Answer (score 21):

You can also use a simple formulas:

**=if( (Condition_A) * (Condition_B) * ... ; true; false)**

make sure to put the condition between parenthesis.

Comment: This solves the problem of filtering based on multiple values on the same row without the use of FILTER function. [In this link](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-formula-for-filtering-data/), there's the example with only a criteria inside of IF fuction