# Multiple Condition IF Statement in ARRAY formula EXCEL

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I am trying to create an array formula in Excel with multiple conditions, however it does not work (results in 0). If I remove the AND and evaluate one condition at a time, the formula works, but I need excel to evaluate all three conditions and sum the values only if all three are met. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks!

WORKS:

```
=SUM(IF($I$2:$I$9999<>"",$U$2:$U$9999))

=SUM(IF(YEAR($I$2:$I$9999)=YEAR(AD2),$U$2:$U$9999))

=SUM($M$2:$M$9999="",$U$2:$U$9999))
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
=SUM(IF(AND($I$2:$I$9999<>"",YEAR($I$2:$I$9999)=YEAR(AD2),$M$2:$M$9999=""),$U$2:$U$9999))
```

Ctrl+Shift+Enter is used to enter the formula.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Array formula IF(multiple criteria)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540719/excel-array-formula-ifmultiple-criteria)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `AND` function in these sort of formulas because it returns a single result, not an array - try using * to simulate `AND`, i.e.

`=SUM(IF(($I$2:$I$9999<>"")*(YEAR($I$2:$I$9999)=YEAR(AD2))*($M$2:$M$9999=""),$U$2:$U$9999))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or an "non-array" version with `SUMPRODUCT`

`=SUMPRODUCT(($I$2:$I$9999<>"")*(YEAR($I$2:$I$9999)=YEAR(AD2))*($M$2:$M$9999=""),$U$2:$U$9999)`

.....or possibly `SUMIFS`

`=SUMIFS($U:$U,$I:$I,">="&DATE(YEAR(AD2),1,1),$I:$I,"<"&DATE(YEAR(AD2)+1,1,1),$M:$M,"")`

Edit: you probably don't need to check that column I is non-blank if you are also checking the YEAR for that column - it can't match the year anyway unless it's possible AD2 might be blank?

Comment: The first formula did that trick (did not test the others). +1 for removing the redundant non-blank year check. You're awesome!