# Formula with IF AND applied to dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I need column C to return today's date, only if column A and B both have a date in them. So if only one of the columns has a date in it then column C needs to remain blank. Column A already has an IF formula in it to populate it with today's date if another criterion is met.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Array formula IF(multiple criteria)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540719/excel-array-formula-ifmultiple-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a value is a date can be a bit troublesome - Excel will treat the number 1 as 1st January 1900 and will return TRUE if you ask if it's a date.

I found this formula which seems to work fairly well in identify a date:
**=OR(CELL("format",A1)={"D1","D2","D3","D4","D5"})**
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/36619-there-%22isdate%22-type-function-excel.html
But, if your cell's formatted as a date but left blank it will still return true.

So, you need to check it's formatted as a date and contains a valid date.

```
=IF(AND(CELL("format",$A1)="D1",CELL("format",$B1)="D1",$A1>0,$B1>0),TODAY(),"")
```

This checks that both cells are formatted as **d-mmm-yy** or **dd-mmm-yy** and contains a value greater than 0. 1st January 1900 will still be accepted as a date - you may want to change the 0 to 42005 (1st January 2015) or some other value.

If you're not formatting your dates as **d-mmm-yy** or **dd-mmm-yy** you'll want to change "D1" for D2, D3, D4 or D5 - look at the help file for the CELL formula for more info.