# Possible to use QUARTILE function over a conditional range in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for something that works like a `quartileif` function (if one existed), but am not sure how to simulate it. There's a table column I want to take the 3rd quartile of, but only if it's within a certain year. Is there a way I could do this in one formula or do I need to just resort to creating multiple tables (which gets messy)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
=QUARTILE(IF((A2:A10>2010)*(A2:A10<2015),B2:B10),3)
```

Since this an array formula, remember to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` after typing it.

Comment: Could you employ this technique? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13937202/2471473

Comment: Yes, edited the answer

Comment: This worked. Interesting... where can I read up more on how to create arrays using formulas? Is there a way to select a set of arbitrary cells to be in an array?

Comment: When asking "Where can I learn more about 'x' in VBA?" the answer is often "from Chip Pearson's site." http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx